# How to create and start a custom service after boot in android?

Tags: android, service, native, boot

I have the full android source code (2.1).
I have a couple of queries.

1. I want to create a custom native service in android. I would like to know how i can do that. Things like where i should include my source files, etc.
2. I would like to know how i can start this native service when my device boots up.
3. How can i write a java application to get the data from this native service?

Please help me with some pointers.

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: StackOverflow has not been a good resource for firmware modifications, such as what you are asking about. I would recommend that you head over to http://source.android.com and search the archives of the various Google Groups, then post to the relevant Google Group if you do not find your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the native sources, but what if you try to just install an application with the required service. All you need to start it up at boot time, as shown in the [article](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=139&lang=en).